# How to disprove existence of (total) derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ open, $f:U\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y) = \sqrt{|xy|}$. Prove that both partials exist in $(0,0)$ but $f$ is not $\mathbb R-$differentiable.

My attempt:
Obviously, the partials exist at $(0,0)$ noting that $f(x,0) = f(0,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$.
But I don't know how to formally disprove the total differentiability of $f$.
Proving discontinuity of the partials is not sufficient. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: As the partials are zero, if the total derivative exists at $(0,0)$ it is zero, so the directional derivative is zero in any direction.

Comment: How does the directional derivative being zero in all directions help me?

Comment: what actually are the directional derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$?

Comment: I have to admit I don't know what point you are trying to make? My course in multivariable calculus was a while ago :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ iff the following limit exists and equals $0$.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(x+0,y+0) - f(0,0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,0) x - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0) y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

This limit doesn't exist because approaching along the lines $y=x$ and $y=2x$ give different results.

Comment: That's not an iff as you have it. It is an iff if you say the limit equals $0.$

Comment: @zhw. fixed; thank you.